# Handling statistics via writing to a file

Tags: java, arrays, file, text, java.util.scanner

For my school project I've been assigned to make a program for a pizzeria.
One of the tasks is to make text file that handles statistics over the amount of pizzas ordered.

I have an array of 30 pizzas to choose from. When a pizza is chosen the index number of said pizza, and the amount of pizzas chosen, needs to be written to the text file.

My question is: How would one do this?

Im writing in Java :-).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you done some research before posting a question? Read how to ask question here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please also read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-write-to-file) article. There are some ways to write something to text file using Java. 
Example from Baeldung:

```java
String str = "Hello";
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
writer.write(str);
    
writer.close();
```

Is it what you are looking for?